# Desire2Learn is_dropped, is_released and status in SOAP and Valence GradeValue object

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm unable to find the "is_dropped", "is_released" and "status" properties or keys from the **GradeValue** object. Well, I'm working on migrating SOAP to Valence and this information is missing from the Valence result set. Do you know any indirect way to get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that, currently, these properties attached to grade values are not directly exposed through the Valence Learning Framework APIs. Note that the `is_released` property may not be necessary after a migration to the Learning Framework APIs: this is only important for final grades, and roles with no permission to enter final grades will receive a 404 if the final grade is not released, so you can infer it from that result. Also, under typical conditions, the `status` property always be 0 (meaning OK).

Desire2Learn acknowledges that functional gaps exist between the D2LWS and Valence platforms around assessment, and they are actively working on closing those gaps. D2LWS will continue to be in place, until the important gaps that D2L's clients have identified become filled. The D2LWS platform has now been deprecated, but that's an indication of D2L's intent to actively close the gapes and assist customers in migrating from D2LWS to the newer, Valence platform.

Comment: Original answer I gave was actually for another question and mistakenly provided here to the wrong question, so I replaced with this answer, the right one, which a moderator then removed for an unexplained reason. So I'm re-entering it.